# Create presentation file using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, powerpoint

I want to create two `.pptx` file with a slide and after creation i want to copy first `.pptx` slide to second `.pptx file` without removing old one.. for example we have two `.pptx`  file that is `ppt1.pptx` and `ppt2.pptx` now i want `ppt2.pptx` slide copy to `ppt1.pptx,` without effecting on ol slide. Please help me for that.

Comment: If you intend to use PowerPoint automation, look at the docs for the InsertFromFile method of the Slides collection:  InsertFromFile(FileName As String, Index As Long, [SlideStart As Long = 1], [SlideEnd As Long = -1]) As Long

Comment: There's solution. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478838/creating-powerpoint-presentations-programmatically

Comment: but how i overwrite it

Comment: >> but how i overwrite it   Which comment does this apply to and what is "it"?  If you want specific answers, you should ask specific questions (and better yet, show the code that you've got so far).

Comment: It related to the ppt file which use in stackoverflow.com/questions/478838/ link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use Aspose components

http://www.aspose.com/.net/powerpoint-component.aspx

or PowerPoint automation

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303718