# How to programmatically create a powerpoint from a list of images

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I've seen this question: [Creating PowerPoint presentations programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478838/creating-powerpoint-presentations-programmatically), but that question asks "Can you?" to which the answer is "yes".

But I'm asking "How?" and specifically "From a list of images?"

Here's what I do to break a ppt up into images

```
var app = new PowerPoint.Application();
var pres = app.Presentations;
var file = pres.Open(input, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
file.SaveAs(output, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsJPG, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
file.Close();
app.Quit();
```

How do I do the reverse?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It'll be something like this:

```
string pictureFileName = "C:\\temp\\test.jpg"; 

Application pptApplication = new Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides slides;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Slide slide;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextRange objText;

// Create the Presentation File
Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Add(MsoTriState.msoTrue);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout = pptPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];

// Create new Slide
slides = pptPresentation.Slides;
slide = slides.AddSlide(1, customLayout);

// Add title
objText = slide.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange;
objText.Text = "test";
objText.Font.Name = "Arial";
objText.Font.Size = 32;

objText = slide.Shapes[2].TextFrame.TextRange;
objText.Text = "Content goes here\nYou can add text\nItem 3";

Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shape = slide.Shapes[2];
slide.Shapes.AddPicture(pictureFileName,Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,shape.Left, shape.Top, shape.Width, shape.Height);

slide.NotesPage.Shapes[2].TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test";

pptPresentation.SaveAs(@"c:\temp\test.pptx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsDefault, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
//pptPresentation.Close();
//pptApplication.Quit();
```

Comment: Is it possible to embed an excel object into powerpoint that is created using Open XML?