# Accessing powerpoint object programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, templates, powerpoint

I am accessing a ppt template in C# and creating a custom output programatically based on data.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations objPresSet = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.Chart chart = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.DataSheet dataSheet = null;

objPres = objPresSet.Open(@"C:\Sample PPT application\WebSite4\WebSite4\2_Soundbite1.pptx", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Slide objSlide = null;
objSlide = objPres.Slides[1];



foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape prefixShape in objSlide.Shapes)
{
    chart = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.Chart)prefixShape.OLEFormat.Object;
    dataSheet = chart.Application.DataSheet;
}
```

Now in case, when the template is of type '.ppt' then `OLEFormat.Object` as used above do exist, where as in case of '.pptx', it gives the following error

> OLEFormat (unknown member) : Invalid request.  This property only
>   applies to OLE objects.

Not able to recognize it, I have searched msdn as well as other sites but no one is distinguishing '.ppt' and '.pptx'.

In the link [Creating PowerPoint presentations programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478838/creating-powerpoint-presentations-programmatically) , its mentioned that we can write a powerpoint programmatically, the problem I am facing is, I am able to do the same when the extension is '.ppt' whereas in case of '.pptx', I am unable to access charts and graphs being used in the template as the OLEFormat.Object that is used in accessing charts is not working in case of '.pptx', am I missing some dll for '.pptx' support, I am currently using 'Assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.dll, v2.0.50727'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating PowerPoint presentations programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478838/creating-powerpoint-presentations-programmatically)

Comment: In the above link, its mentioned that we can write a powerpoint programmatically, the problem I am facing is, I am able to do the same when the extension is '.ppt' whereas in case of '.pptx', I am unable to access charts and graphs being used in the template as the OLEFormat.Object that is used in accessing charts is not working in case of '.pptx', am I missing some dll for '.pptx' support, I am currently using 'Assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.dll, v2.0.50727'

Comment: Your code doesn't check the type of shape? Is it a chart type or is it a MSGraph chart object.

Answer (score 0):

```
objSlide[1].Shapes["myObjectNameInsideSlide1"].TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Kiko";
```

The above code will access the textbox/shape inside the slide 1