# Merge Fields Using PowerPoint and C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I need to create a report that outputs data to a an MS Powerpoint presentation w/c is pretty similar to mail merge in MS Word. Basically I have a templated MS Powerpoint with data that needs to be updated dynamically. I also need the presentation charts to be updated.

Is there any SDKs/ out of the .NET box solution that I can use to achieve this? I have found below SDK but the tutorial for MS Powerpoint is missing.

http://ericwhite.com/blog/introduction-to-open-xml-series/

Comment: you can easily interact with any office application, including  powerpoint using its dedicated microsoft interop libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478838/creating-powerpoint-presentations-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using Open Office XML Power Tools

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools/blob/vNext/OpenXmlPowerToolsExamples/PresentationBuilder02/PresentationBuilder02.cs