# Can SSIS export to a PowerPoint Slide

Tags: ssis, powerpoint

I have this project where I need to generate PowerPoint slide as a report for management. SSRS is not an option, so I was wondering if SSIS can export to a PowerPoint file?

Comment: Please spend some time expanding the details of what you have tried and what you think is required. This is not a place that responds to lazy questions. "PowerPoint slide as a report for managerment" is a very generic request.

Comment: I appreciate the response. However, it wasn't intended to be lazy, but more of a straight forward question. I know, for a fact, that CastIron can export data into a CSV, TXT, and XML format. However, for XSLX, it requires a web service to be written, and then called to then export into that format.

So SSIS, does it have the ability to export data into a PowerPoint file format, or would a custom web service need to be created, for it to call, to accomplish this goal? Or is it even possible? I've done some research and i'm having a hard time finding an answer. Hence why I came here.

Comment: no, there are no out of box "PowerPoint" destination connectors for SSIS.  Only thing I could think of that MIGHT work would be create your own custom C# script task.  Have a look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478838/creating-powerpoint-presentations-programmatically

Comment: Thank you for the response! I really appreciate it.